# Viewing datetime in ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I need ti display with ng-table in one column datetime:

var renderGrid = function(tableData) {

```
        $scope.tableData = tableData;

        if($scope.tableParams) { 
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        } else {
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
                sorting: {
                    date: 'asc'
                },
                filter: {
                    date: ''
                }
            }, {
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    var sliceStart = (params.page() - 1) * params.count();
                    var sliceEnd = params.page() * params.count();
                    var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.tableData, params.filter()) : $scope.tableData;
                    var filteredData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tableData;
                    $scope.totalCount = filteredData.length;
                    params.total(filteredData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(filteredData.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd));
                }
            });                     
        }
    };

    <table ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="tcTableNav" class="tcTable">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
                <td style="width:34%" sortable="'date'" data-title="'Date'"><div>{{item.date}}</div></td>
            <td style="width:33%" sortable="'autor'" data-title="'Autor'"><div>{{item.autor}}</div></td>
            <td style="width:33%" sortable="'article'" data-title="'Article'"><div>{{item.article}}</div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

How form datetime correctly that sorting + filtering work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

i solved that by adding a textfield with the formatted date to my tableData

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using instead ngTasty table http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table ,
and if you want you can just upload an example of the structure you want sort and I will write you the complete solution :)